# How to create a scrollable view with a collection view on the top and the list on the bottom?

Tags: ios, layout

This is a picture from the Ganna app in the app store:

[image]

This view pops up when the user clicks on the search bar at the top. I believe they implemented it using a `UISearchController` (passing in a `ScrollView` to the constructor of the `UISearchController`) and that `ScrollView` further contains a horizontal scrolling `CollectionView` for the Recent Searches (on the top) but I am confused how they put the trending list below that. Is that a `TableView` for the Trending section?

Does anyone have another idea how to build this type of UI?

EDIT:

Would a single TableView work with the header being Recent Searches collectionview and the rest being the table view cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 'Recent Search' scrolled up when you scroll entire view? (i can't find this app in my app store'

If so, you can customize table cell to two different type and use 'collectionview' inside your first section.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell!
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id of cell contain colletoinview for recent search", for: indexPath)
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id of cell for trending", for: indexPath)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

If not, you can use both 'collection view' and 'table view' in your uiviewcontroller.

```
class SampleController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var trendingTableView : UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var recentSearchCollectionView : UICollectionView!
}

extension SampleController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // handle your tableview, Implement protocol
}

extension SampleController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // handle your collectionview, Implement protocol
}
```

You can even customize scrollview.(Really not recommended)

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same as your first option too actually. You can also make the Recent Searches `CollectionView` a header cell and the remaining bottom part normally dequeing cells. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very happy to help you. :)

Comment: In SnapChat I was wondering how would you go about creating the view that is displayed when you click on the search bar in snapchat? I was thinking to have one big `TableView`. Then inside that main `TableView` create a section called `Top Stories` and put a `CollectionView` in there. Then for the next portion have another section with all of the categories like (`Around Me`, `Travel`, etc.). Then in that section have a horizontal `CollectionView` with as many cells as categories and a vertical `CollectionView` in each of those cells. Is that a way you would go about?

Comment: Just looking for some input haha?

Comment: I read for a long time, but also with the Google translation, but I still do not understand, would you please provide some image~

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Yes this is the picture: http://imgur.com/DWTArP6. Please let me know how you would go about creating a view like this.

Comment: Is my English is not good. Did you mean that you have a original view controller, and displaying these searching target when user click searchbar?

Comment: Yes exactly. When you click the searchbar, the view similar to the picture I posted above shows up. Also is it possible for you to download SnapChat? It will be much easier for you to visualize how it looks.

Comment: Yes exactly that's the app. Sorry for the late reply I had an event to go to recently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149271/discussion-between-codus-and-1290).